# Why does LDR sometimes take 20 CPU cycles?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, microcontroller

I am having and issue with the LDR and STR instructions in **ARM Cortex M4 assembly**. For some reason, they take way longer to write/read certain parts in memory than to others.

**To illustrate this, I’ve setup this simple example:**

I have created a project with a main C file, and a neighboring “.S” file containing the assembly code. I’ve included the assembly functions into my C file using the “extern” object.

```
//Add the asm functions to our C code
extern "C" void LoadTest(uint32_t *memory_adress);
extern "C" void LoadTestLoop(uint32_t *memory_adress);
```

**Here is what the program does:**

```
void perform_test()
{
  //Time
  register uint32_t register_before_time=before_time;
  register uint32_t register_after_time=after_time;

  register uint32_t* input_address=0x400E9000;
  
  register_before_time=ARM_DWT_CYCCNT; 

  //Time measurment occurs in here!
  LoadTestLoop(input_address);
  
  register_after_time=ARM_DWT_CYCCNT;

  Serial.print(" Time: ");
  Serial.println(register_after_time-register_before_time-time_error);
}
```

It shows us the time it’s taken something to execute in between the
*“register_before_time=ARM_DWT_CYCCNT;”* and *“register_after_time=ARM_DWT_CYCCNT;”* lines.

**Here are the assembly subroutines we will be testing for their speed:**

```
.global LoadTest
LoadTest:
    ldr r1, [r0]                        /*Load value into r1 from memory_address*/
    orr r1, #0xC0                       /*OR bits 7,6 to be on.*/
    str r1, [r0]                        /*Store the changed value back into memory_address*/
    bx lr
```

```
.global LoadTestLoop
LoadTestLoop:
    mov r2, #255                        /* Set r2 to be 255 for the loop*/
    
    TestLoop:                           /*Same code as before*/
        ldr r1, [r0]                        
        orr r1, #0xC0                   
        str r1, [r0]
        
        subs r2, r2, #1                 /*Decrement r2 + set Z flag if it's zero*/
        bne TestLoop                    /*Repeat until r2==0*/
    bx lr
```

**LoadTest** – Loads a value from the address we give it. ORs the value with 0xC0 and then stores it back to the same address.

**LoadTestLoop** – Does the same thing, however, does it in a loop 255 times, this way we can get a average of how long one loop iteration takes, and minimize the time measurement errors from the branching instructions going in and out of the function.

**Note:** To also minimize measurement errors, the address to work on is provided to both functions outside of the time measurement zone, in the input_address pointer.

```
register uint32_t* input_address=0x400E9000;
```

**Test results and the issue:**

I ran these two tests for both normal C variables

```
uint32_t test_value=255;
register uint32_t* input_address=&test_value;
```

And for the configuration registers inside the microcontrollers. Note that in the datasheet they are presented as just memory.

```
register uint32_t* input_address=0x400E9000;
```

**On average LoadTest for standard variables took 9 cycles to execute, but much longer at 27 cycles for the control registers.** The LoadTestLoop tests reinforced this with standard variables taking on average 1541 cycles (6 cycles per iteration) and the control registers a astounding 12227 cycles, which works out to a crazy 47 cycles per iteration!

**Why is this happening?**

Why does LDR and STR sometimes take way longer to execute? Does it have something to do with the little “b” written next to the cycle count on [this instruction set website](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Programmers-Model/Instruction-set-summary/Cortex-M4-instructions?lang=en)? Clicking on it sends you back to the same page.
[image: Notice the little blue b next to the number 2]

Does anybody know why this is happening? I’ve been bugged by this question for a long time and would really like to know.

Thank You for the help

Comment: `extern "C"` is invalid C. You're programming in C++. And in C++ the `register` keyword unused (but reserved).

Comment: LDR is a memory access instruction, so it is largely depending on the memory interface. It can also access cached memory, so the access time will vary pretty much.

Comment: Control register access might be much longer because these are not normal memory, which can be cached + each access might have certain hardware side-effects which take time before the transaction is acknowledged and LDR finished.

Comment: What is at address 0x400E9000?

Comment: 0x4xxxxxxx would be a peripheral and those can run off a different clock from the cpu clock and not just for all the other list of reasons why a simple load or store can take dozens to hundreds of clocks, certainly if you are tapping into a different clock domain you have that, and then the peripherals take as long as they take per register per whatever is going on at the time, the transaction may get held off not just because of clock domains but also priority of access of a resource within a peripheral (multi-ported memory, flip flops/registers, etc).

Comment: 20 clocks is not bad actually.

Comment: you are better off with timing accuracy reading the timer before and after the test loop. the systick will give the same results as the debug clock if they designed it with the systick timer getting the cpu clock.   Also note that alignment of the loop can have at least some affect on the performance so try it with at least a halfword adjustment as the cortex-ms do not tend to have much of a fetch line, either they fetch one halfword at a time or a whole word.  With a whole word you can sometimes see the effects of that  for a tight loop test like this.

Comment: even if that were simply an sram read, the system design is done by the chip vendor not arm.  The busses have handshakes (go look at the documentation).  Flashes are slow relative to the system clock although newer technology is creeping into the mcus now, not just forced caches (STM32), so typically if you were to read a flash location you would expect that to have at least one wait state (until the last few years or so) that you cannot control even at the slowest cpu clock rates, and then as you increase the cpu clock rate the wait states go up....

Comment: but sram itself is also in the domain of the chip vendor and their logic or purchased ip to implement the bus interface, etc.  as these cortex-mcus get faster I expect to see wait states on the sram start to show up as well, but we will see.   Definitely though if you cross over into the peripheral domain you should expect many clocks.  and depending on the peripheral and what is going on with that peripheral and chip, the time to vary.

Comment: You should also disable interrupts during the test.  The performance of peripheral register access is implementation dependent, and not a function of the Cortex-M core.  Picking some random peripheral address is also non deterministic - not all peripherals will necessarily behave in the same manner.  Comparing SRAM access to I/O access is not apples with apples.

Comment: @old_timer :  Cortex-M parts fast enough to require SRAM wait-states exist, but tupically use a Cortex-M7 core which has data and instruction caches to mitigate that.

Comment: Footnote b is at the bottom of that table and says "Neighboring load and store single instructions can pipeline their address and data phases. This enables these instructions to complete in a single execution cycle."  That's not relevant to your question.  More relevant is the note at the top: "The cycle counts are based on a system with zero wait states."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely normal.

In general, a load from memory takes as long as it takes.  The timing isn't under the control of the CPU itself, so a quoted cycle count can only represent a "best case".  If the CPU can't fulfill the load from its own internal structures (e.g. store buffer or L1 cache), then it just has to put the request out on the memory bus and stall until the memory subsystem responds.  (Or go on executing later instructions out-of-order, if so equipped and if it can find some that don't depend on the result of the load.)

The actual time taken can be highly variable, depending for instance on whether the load hits or misses L2 or L3 cache, whether another core or external device holds a bus lock, etc.  If the machine has no cache and all memory is fast SRAM, then the time could be pretty stable.

But in your case the address you're loading is actually mapped to a hardware device.  So you're not really reading RAM at all, you're doing I/O.  In this case, the response has to come from the device itself, and the device can essentially take as long as it needs.  If you need to be able to predict the time, then you need to be looking at the documentation of that device (and any interface hardware in between), not at cycle counts in the CPU manual.

Comment: In this case it's a Cortex-M4, which can't have any cache, even L1, and has a very short in-order pipeline.  Not sure about a store-buffer or the possibility of any memory-level parallelism for multiple in-flight loads or stores even for memory, not I/O.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Silicon_customization shows it can't be customized with TCM either for data or instructions.  ("Tightly-Coupled Memory (TCM): Low-latency RAM that is used to hold critical routines, data, stacks")